# Clear select2 with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm using an Angular directive to build up a select using Select2.
I've put this construction inside a `link` function, as seen here:

```
var selectProducts = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        replace: true,

        scope: false,

        template: '<select id="products_list" ng-model="product.id" ng-change="setProduct()"></select>',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).select2({
                placeholder: 'Select...',
                width: '100%',
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                ajax: {
                    url: 'url/to/products',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function(params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term,
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function(data, page) {
                        return {
                            results: data
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                }
            });
        }
    };
};
```

But I have to clean the selection after an action triggered by the user. After some search, to clean the Select2 we have to:

```
$(element).val(null);
$(element).trigger('change');
```

When I do it, Angular gets crazy and triggers an error. Following the stack trace, we get here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply

I've done what they are telling to do (using a timeout to do my actions because there are two `apply` calls). But now, the select does not get clean and the selected option is still there. Before, it was cleaned, but with the errors triggered.

```
        scope.$watch(attrs.clean, function(value) {
            if ( value ) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    // Got from https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply
                    if ( scope.$eval(attrs.clean) ) {
                        $(element).val(null);
                        $(element).trigger("change");
                    }
                }, 0, false);
            }
        });
```

Is there a better way to do it? This `timeout` call sounds weird (and does not work!)

Comment: Your way is so jquery

Comment: Is there a better way? I would like to use select2, and I have to use it thorough jQuery

Comment: Does anybody knows something about this?